# crear data frame pandas con archivo seleccionado

Tags: python

Tengo una aplicación que:

Abra un cuadro de diálogo para seleccionar un primer archivo y guarde el texto de la ruta en una etiqueta. Habrá un segundo cuadro de diálogo para seleccionar un segundo archivo y guarde el texto de la ruta en una etiqueta

Lo que quiero ahora es con los dos archivos seleccionados, leerlos con pandas y crear un data frame con lo dos archivos seleccionados y después trabajar con datos y columnas (tengo que hacer un split y comparación de datos de dos columnas)

lo que no se como hacer es leer esos archivos que seleccione con pandas para poder generar el dataframe. o utilizar la ruta seleccionada para read_excel.

```
from ventana_ui import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QColorDialog, QDialog,
        QErrorMessage, QFileDialog, QFontDialog, QFrame, QGridLayout,
        QInputDialog, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPushButton)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.BotonCliente.clicked.connect(self.setOpenFileName)
        self.ArchivoC.setText("Haz clic en el botón para seleccionar")
        self.BotonAfip.clicked.connect(self.setOpenFileName2)
        self.ArchivoA.setText("Haz clic en el botón para seleccionar")
        ##self.Comparar.clicked.connect(self.ComparaExcel) 
        ##self.filters = "Excel Files (*.xls *xlsx)"
     
     
       
    def setOpenFileName(self):   
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", self.ArchivoC.text(),
                "Excel Files (*.xls *xlsx)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            self.ArchivoC.setText(fileName)
       
    def setOpenFileName2(self):   
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", self.ArchivoA.text(),
                "Excel Files (*.xls *xlsx)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            self.ArchivoA.setText(fileName) 
              
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: no todo proyecto que use PyQt implica que todos sus problemas implique pyqt5, en tu caso PyQt ya hizo su trabajo: obtener la ruta del archivo y nada mas. Analiza y evita abusar de los tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el archivo que quieres leer es excel, es muy sencillo:

```
import pandas as pd

datos1_df = pd.read_excel("ruta/al/archivo/excel.xlsx")
```

Puedes usar otras funciones como `read_csv` para csv o `reqd_sql` para BB.DD SQL. Puedes ver todos los ficheros que puede leer Pandas, en su documentación que está muy bien hecha y tiene muchos ejemplos [aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/io.html)

### Update.

En el caso de que lo almacenes en una variable que le pides al usuario, le puedes pasar la variable, como siempre se puede hacer en Python:

```
import pandas as pd

ruta_usuario = "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/datos_usuario.xlsx"

#Le pasamos la variable ruta usuario
datos1_df = pd.read_excel(ruta_usuario)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Alberto, lo que necesitaría es pasarle la ruta seleccionada en cada QFileDialog.getOpenFileName sabes como hacerlo?

Comment: Tienes ya la ruta donde se encuentra? O no sabes como obtenerla?

Comment: sisi es la que selecciona el usuario y la guardo como texto con esta funcion (tengo dos funciones para dos archivos para armar despues el DF)                                                                                                                
       def setOpenFileName(self):   
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", self.ArchivoC.text(),
                "Excel Files (*.xls *xlsx)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            self.ArchivoC.setText(fileName)

Comment: pues entonces, lo único que tienes que hacer es pasarle ese texto directamente, o la variable en la que guardas dicho texto. Te he puesto un update en la pregutna, no sé si te estoy entendiendo bien.

Comment: perfecto lo pruebo muchas gracias lo que no sabia es como insertar la variable como ruta del archivo. Saludos!!

Comment: De nada, como eres nuevo probablemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es dandole un voto positivo a mi respuesta, y porque no, si te ha ayudado a resolver tu problema, marcarla como respuesta correcta. Esto no solo me dará a mí reputación por haberte ayudado, si no que ayudará a posicionar mejor tu pregunta, para que si alguien en un futuro tiene la misma duda que tú, pueda encontrar la solución. :)